# How to print a return statement from an Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, composite, complex-data-types

so Im trying to get my code to print out a message that returns 'This is Bob Martin from USA'.

This is what I did so far. I've been trying to figure out what went wrong but can't seem to get this to work. I provided comments to guide my thought processes

---

```js
function printBio(user) {

  // function to print message, user is the object and parameter for my function 

  // User object that possesses properties as displayed

  let user = {
    name: 'Bob',
    surname: 'Martin',
    age: 25,
    address: '',
    country: "USA"
  }
}

    return 'This is ' + user.name + ' ' + user.surname + ' from ' + user.country + '.';

    // My attempt for a return statement to print my desired message   

    printBio();

    // The last step, which is to simply have the function do its job and print the message according to the return statement

}
```

Comment: `console.log(printBio())`

Comment: seems you placed the call to printBio(); inside the function after the return, which wont work

Comment: The code editor button is your friend `[<>]` it opens up to a world of possibilities like legible code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a built in method to tag onto your user object:

```
class User {
    constructor(name, surname, age, address, country) {
    this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname, 
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.country = country;
    }

    printBioMethod() {
        const bio = `This is ${this.name} ${this.surname} from ${this.country}.`;
        console.log(bio);
    }
}
```

Or If you prefer an external function to pull out the objects variables

```
const printBioFunction = obj => {
    const { name, surname, country } = obj;
    const bio = `This is ${name} ${surname} from ${country}.`;

    console.log(bio);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function printBio(user) {
  return `This is ${user.name} ${user.surname} from ${user.address.country}.`
}
```

This is the solution that was given by the platform